# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule Redirects without parameter

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm want to redirect a custom URL same like example in docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

EX: http://domain.com/find/324 to http://domain.com/?text=324

This is the code , for some reason it keeps redirect me to homepage without the parameter "text" in the URL..

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('find/(.+)/?', 'index.php?text=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

The "text" parameter is not a build in WoprPress function, i'm going to use it with custom code of mine.

I flushed that links cache, still redirects to homepage without the parameters.

What i'm missing?

Comment: I believe you should use `'find/(\d+)/?'` (or `'find/([^/]+)/?'`) otherwise, the `/` will be eaten with `.+`.

Comment: @stribizhev Dosent work with those options too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add custom query vars directly. Custom query vars have to be added using the query_vars filter to be parsed within rules. You can add custom query vars as seen below.

```
function wpd_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'text'; //I used the one in your example
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_vars' );
```

Then you get get the query vars like this:

```
get_query_var('text')
```

check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271931/add-rewrite-rule-parameter-is-not-received-by-the-page?rq=1 for more detail.